# Chrome extension to capture video of last few minutes of active tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I am trying to write a Chrome plugin to capture a video of the active tab. My code is based on [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder?hl=en).

When my page action is invoked, I start the recording:

```
var recordedChunks = null;

var captureOptions = { audio : false, video : true };
chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, 
    function(stream) {
        if (stream) {
            recordedChunks = [];
            var options = {mimeType: "video/webm"};
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {                  
                    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
);
```

When the page action is invoked again, I stop the recording and download a file as:

```
mediaRecorder.stop();
var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/webm'
});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = 'display: none';
a.href = url;
a.download = 'test.webm';
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

This works great - I am able to play the downloaded `test.webm` video.

But I only want to record the *last few minutes of video* of the active tab. I do not want the `recordedChunks` array to grow unbounded. So, I tried something like this in the start recording action:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, 
    function(stream) {
        // ...
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {                  
                    recordedChunks.push(event.data);

                    // CHANGE HERE: keep only the last 1000 blobs
                    while (recordedChunks.length > 1000) {
                        recordedChunks.shift();
                    }
                }
            }           
    }
);
```

But with this modification, the download `test.webm` video is not playable. How do I capture just the tail of the blob output from MediaRecorder?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're deleting the beginning of the file? Every file starts with some headers (file information) and then comes all the data.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez Good point, let me try deleting from after a few chunks

Comment: @SamuelMéndez that did not work, at least not the naive way I tried (delete the 5-th element always)

Comment: Then you can use a library like ffmpeg to cut the video, but that is video post-processing...

Comment: It's an interesting goal, but likely to be a very hard problem. The video output you're getting is compressed; to play it, it needs a certain structure and metadata; just throwing away parts of it make the structure invalid and metadata invalid. It's theoretically possible to decide where to cut it so that the structure is as required, but you'll need a new metadata block for it. So, you'll need to learn how this particular video compression works.